# Selenium Chrome Webdriver memory leak problem

Tags: linux, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to crawl some websites using c# selenium chrome Webdriver. I'm calling driver.Close() and driver.Quit() method after each request. Running without any problem. But after I containerized this .Net 5.0 application using docker and I saw some memory issues. The memory of the container increased after each step slowly. And after a while memory is filling up even there isn't any chrome instance and any process(I saw using "top" command).
I'm wondering that how is memory filling up even there isn't any process? How to solve that issue?